# How do I move the position of this image?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to move these images created with javascript. I have multiple images created with javascript and when I press the button to generate them, all the pictures stack up left to right in the order they were created. I want to position some of them on the website. Not sure how to do it.

Here is the code for one of the images that is created with javascript, the others are the exact same, just different names:

```
var headPic = document.createElement("img");
  headPic.src = headList[head];
  document.body.appendChild(headPic);
```

Comment: What you want to do is use CSS.

Comment: By *"position some of them on the website"*, do you mean the viewport?

Comment: the placement of each image on the website. right now it just loads in a single horizontal line. pictures load left to right respectively.

Comment: `document.createElement("img").position` is undefined, so your code is doomed to failure from the first line

Comment: May we see your CSS? I got my images to wrap in this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/yd-han/pen/BggEjR).

Comment: i dont got any CSS LOL. im a newbie, just trying to get this thing done for a friend.

Comment: @khan this is currently how mine works right now (except there are multiple pictures at once left to right). how do i place these pictures somewhere else on the website? i'm trying to mimic a slot of a inventory in a game.

Comment: @bmoo63b, I updated my CodePen. You can create a container, use `display: grid`, and append your images into that container. You can research more about Grids [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout).

Answer (score -1):

You can consider using flexbox.

You can refer to the
[web page](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/):

You can also try my code.

```js
headList=[];
headList[0]="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/1373/1373204.svg";
headList[1]="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/1373/1373203.svg";
headList[2]="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/1373/1373208.svg";
function go()
{
  var container=document.getElementById("container");
    for (var i=0;i<headList.length;i++)
    {
     var img=document.createElement("img");
      img.src=headList[i];
      container.append(img);
    }
}
```

```css
div.container
{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="container">

</div>
<button onclick="go()">
  Go
</button>
```

Comment: You can stack up the generated images from left to right by using flexbox.